# HPLIP gives a error messages when trying to installing plug-in for HP P1102W-printer

Tags: 14.04, hplip

I had a HP P1102W-printer installed on my Ubuntu 14.04. I used some program from HP that already had the drivers (no download) and made a successful installation... no issues.

After formatting the HDD and reinstalling the OS I could not find that HP-program again but tried HPLIP instead (3.15.7 and 3.15.6). But HPLIP can not find or download the necessary plug-in.

I have tested the "hp-doctor" that suggest that I should download the missing driver from internet/ HP-server. But all efforts ends with the same error message.

Error message:

```
Checking for network connection...
Downloading plug-in from: 
error: Plugin download failed with error code = 8
error:  file does not match its checksum. File may have been corrupted or altered
```

Any suggestions?? Is this problem with my PC or is it with the HP-server. Can the old installation program from HP be found somewhere (not HPLIP)?

Found additional reference..
https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/269395

Answer (score 0):

Recently got exactly the same problem. The best option is to perform an manual installation. The GUI/Wizard seems to have some issues.

What I did to solve this issue was to grab the plugin from this location https://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/auxfiles/HP/plugins/hplip-3.15.7-plugin.run  because this match the version of the hplip tool installed on my system.

After downloading, I opened a terminal console and typed hp-plugin 
in the Wizard, specify the location of the file you have just download 
At the end you should see a successful message..

Reboot your machine and give it a try

He worked for me. I hope it will work for you.

Comment: I seems that sourceforg server is down.
http://sourceforge.net/blog/category/status-updates/

No matter what HPLIP I run will work as long as the source server is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This Morning (23/7, 2015), My HPLIP got connection with HPLIP source
server(http://hplip.sourceforge.net/plugin.conf) and downloaded the
conf-file and I could finalize the installation of my printer.